# To fill the missing data lines with pandas reindex function

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I am trying to fill the missing lines in my time series data using pandas reindex function.

My data looks like:

```
 100,2007,239,4,29.588,-30.851,-999.0,-999.0,-999.0,-999.00,13.125,-999.00
 100,2007,239,5,29.573,-30.843,-999.0,-999.0,-999.0,-999.00,13.126,-999.00
 100,2007,239,14,29.389,-30.880,-999.0,-999.0,-999.0,-999.00,13.131,-999.00
 100,2007,239,15,29.367,-30.901,-999.0,-999.0,-999.0,-999.00,13.131,-999.00
 100,2007,239,24,29.374,-30.920,-999.0,-999.0,-999.0,-999.00,13.135,-999.00
```

It is timeseries data for one day with one minute time interval which the fourth column indicates. Unlikely to normal time series index, time index of this data look like 0 to 59, 100 to 159 ....2300 to 2359 because 1 day is 24 hours and 1 hour is 60 minutes. So, fill the gap with 'nan' value, I made the code as bellow:

```
S = []
for i in range(0,24):

     s = np.arange(i*100,i*100+60)
     s = list(s)
S = S + s

pd.set_option('max_rows',10)
for INPUT in FileList:
     output = INPUT + "result" # set the output files
     data=pd.read_csv(INPUT,sep=',',index_col=[3],parse_dates=[3])
     index = 'S'#make the reference index to fill
     df = data
     sk_f = df.reindex(index)       
     sk_f.to_csv(output,na_rep='nan')
```

By this code, I purposed to fill the gap by the line of 'nan' following the indice in the fourth column based on S which is the reference index.
But the result is just the rows of 'nan' rather than filling the gap as below:

```
,100,2007,241,22.471,-31.002,-999.0,-999.0.1,-999.0.2,-999.00,13.294,-999.00    .1
0,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan
1,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan 
2,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan
3,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan
4,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan
5,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan
6,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan
7,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan 
8,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan
9,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan
10,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan
11,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan
```

My expectation is to fill the gap of missing lines in the original data. For example, in the original data, there is no lows between 0 to 3 index line. So I would like to fill those lines with original data format.
I may miss something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I find problematic indent with create list `S = S + s`. You have to use, because list `S` kept only last `s`:

```
S = []
for i in range(0,24):

     s = np.arange(i*100,i*100+60)
     s = list(s)
S = S + s #keep only last s
```

to:

```
S = []
for i in range(0,24):
    s = np.arange(i*100,i*100+60)
    s = list(s)
    S = S + s
```

or shorter:

```
S = []
for i in range(0,24):
    S = S + list(np.arange(i*100,i*100+60))
```

Next is problematic `index = 'S'` I think, it is typo and it can be `index = S`. 
You can add function `bfill()` and fill gaps backward. [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#cleaning-filling-missing-data)

```
sk_f = df.reindex(index).bfill()
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

S = []
for i in range(0,24):
    S = S + list(np.arange(i*100,i*100+60))

#original data
temp=u"""100,2007,239,4,29.588,-30.851,-999.0,-999.0,-999.0,-999.00,13.125,-999.00
100,2007,239,5,29.573,-30.843,-999.0,-999.0,-999.0,-999.00,13.126,-999.00
100,2007,239,14,29.389,-30.880,-999.0,-999.0,-999.0,-999.00,13.131,-999.00
100,2007,239,15,29.367,-30.901,-999.0,-999.0,-999.0,-999.00,13.131,-999.00
100,2007,239,24,29.374,-30.920,-999.0,-999.0,-999.0,-999.00,13.135,-999.00"""

#pd.set_option('max_rows',10)

data=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp),sep=',', header=None, index_col=[3], parse_dates=[3])
data.index.name = None
print data

#     0     1    2       4       5    6    7    8    9       10   11
#4   100  2007  239  29.588 -30.851 -999 -999 -999 -999  13.125 -999
#5   100  2007  239  29.573 -30.843 -999 -999 -999 -999  13.126 -999
#14  100  2007  239  29.389 -30.880 -999 -999 -999 -999  13.131 -999
#15  100  2007  239  29.367 -30.901 -999 -999 -999 -999  13.131 -999
#24  100  2007  239  29.374 -30.920 -999 -999 -999 -999  13.135 -999

index = S #make the reference index to fill
df = data
sk_f = df.reindex(index).bfill()

print sk_f.head(20)
#     0     1    2       4       5    6    7    8    9       10   11
#0   100  2007  239  29.588 -30.851 -999 -999 -999 -999  13.125 -999
#1   100  2007  239  29.588 -30.851 -999 -999 -999 -999  13.125 -999
#2   100  2007  239  29.588 -30.851 -999 -999 -999 -999  13.125 -999
#3   100  2007  239  29.588 -30.851 -999 -999 -999 -999  13.125 -999
#4   100  2007  239  29.588 -30.851 -999 -999 -999 -999  13.125 -999
#5   100  2007  239  29.573 -30.843 -999 -999 -999 -999  13.126 -999
#6   100  2007  239  29.389 -30.880 -999 -999 -999 -999  13.131 -999
#7   100  2007  239  29.389 -30.880 -999 -999 -999 -999  13.131 -999
#8   100  2007  239  29.389 -30.880 -999 -999 -999 -999  13.131 -999
#9   100  2007  239  29.389 -30.880 -999 -999 -999 -999  13.131 -999
#10  100  2007  239  29.389 -30.880 -999 -999 -999 -999  13.131 -999
#11  100  2007  239  29.389 -30.880 -999 -999 -999 -999  13.131 -999
#12  100  2007  239  29.389 -30.880 -999 -999 -999 -999  13.131 -999
#13  100  2007  239  29.389 -30.880 -999 -999 -999 -999  13.131 -999
#14  100  2007  239  29.389 -30.880 -999 -999 -999 -999  13.131 -999
#15  100  2007  239  29.367 -30.901 -999 -999 -999 -999  13.131 -999
#16  100  2007  239  29.374 -30.920 -999 -999 -999 -999  13.135 -999
#17  100  2007  239  29.374 -30.920 -999 -999 -999 -999  13.135 -999
#18  100  2007  239  29.374 -30.920 -999 -999 -999 -999  13.135 -999
#19  100  2007  239  29.374 -30.920 -999 -999 -999 -999  13.135 -999
```